# mdbootstrap: hidden floating buttons overlay content

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, material-design, mdbootstrap

I am using the mdbootstrap Pro 4.5.5 version and have the following problem.
For providing context based actions i use the fixed buttons:

https://mdbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#fixed-buttons

As us can see in the screen, the component overlays an hidden unordered list above the content. in this list the buttons are shown on hover or on click on mobile:

[image: inspect fixed buttons]

Problem is: if i have some links or other actions below the hidden list (that could happen on mobile, as u can see on the second scren), they are not clickable and the buttons are already shown when i will touch or click on the links under the list.

[image]

Would be very happy, if somebody could help. I am also happy about other examples or solutions to implement a fab-button-bar on html and js

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (more a hack than a solution) by myself. it depends on the init of velocity on the openFABMenu and closeFABMenu, where only the opacity is set to 0. that only hides the buttons but the container is already there:

```
    var closeFABMenu = function closeFABMenu(btn) {
    $this = btn;
    // Get direction option
    var horizontal = $this.hasClass('horizontal');
    var offsetY = void 0,
    offsetX = void 0;

    if (horizontal === true) {
    offsetX = 40;
    } else {
    offsetY = 40;
    }

    $this.removeClass('active');
    var time = 0;
    $this.find('ul .btn-floating').velocity('stop', true);
    $this.find('ul .btn-floating').velocity({
    opacity: '0',
    scaleX: '.4',
    scaleY: '.4',
    translateY: offsetY + 'px',
    translateX: offsetX + 'px'
    }, {
    duration: 80,
    **display: "none"**
    });
```

For now i overwrote the functions closeFABMenu/openFABMenu and inserted display: none and display:block on the inits of velocity.

atm it works for me, we hope the best. but the solution is not very clean, because i needed also to do some changes on css and html. wondering, that i am the only person with that overlaying problem....